# How to keep track of winners in a spleef Minecraft tournament?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm holding a spleef Minecraft tournament for my students. So I downloaded [the SuperSpleef plugin](http://dev.bukkit.org/server-mods/super-spleef/). Problem is I don't know how to keep track of score and see which of my students won... I want to award prizes, so it's important that the score is accurate. Is SuperSpleef the plugin I should use?

Comment: Depending on how big the tournament is, you might not need a specialized plug-in. For small groups, you could simply just rely on an honor system.

Comment: 15-20 kids, I'm not keen on the honor system in this situation :)

Answer (score 3):

If you were to use the new scoreboard functionality introduced in the new snapshots you could keep track of how many times each player has died and remove them from the game without the use of plugins. By the end of the tournament there'd only be one player left whom you could then declare the winner. If you're not willing to use the snapshots (they're pretty much as stable as the actual releases) and the release of 1.5 is too far away then you'll have to use server plugins which I can't help you with cause I know nothing about them, sorry.

If you are interested in using the command blocks and scoreboard functionality I could always knock something together for you if you want?

Comment: The asker is using a CraftBukkit server, so using a snapshot of vanilla Minecraft is probably not an option.

Comment: Ah, ok. Fair enough then. Good luck with the spleef tournament and I hope you get this sorted :D

Comment: I don't mind using a vanilla Minecraft if that's a better option

Answer (score 3):

You should probably be below the spleef zone to see which students fall below the ground. In the chat HUD, it will say `Student tried to swim in lava` if there is lava below the spleef zone. The neat thing is that the chat orders the deaths from first death to last man standing. I would recommend the second option because it will be simpler to mark the death order from 1st to last killed.

Comment: However, the OP must be online to see these messages.

Answer (score 2):

You can just make everyone put on OP and put lava under the spleef zone and the chat box will list the names of the students who tried to swim in lava. And that is all you need to do!

Comment: Opping an entire classroom of teenagers is a terrible idea.

Comment: The chat will tell you the message regardless of if they are OP or not.

Answer (score 1):

You could put lava under the spleef zone (or something that will kill your students). Turning on hardcore mode in `server.properties` will make it so that only the victor will be able to log in after your tournament.